# Find conditional MAX of only visible cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find the highest score individuals achieved on a test, given that they failed the test, and I want to be able to use filters to narrow down to certain groups of individuals, which I've tried using the SUBTOTAL function to achieve.

Here's what I've tried so far:

SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(104,OFFSET(INDEX(TOTAL,1),ROW(TOTAL)-ROW(INDEX(TOTAL,1)),0,1)),--(PASS_FAIL="FAIL"))

'TOTAL' and 'PASS_FAIL' are named ranges for the individual's score on the test and whether they passed or failed it, respectively.

I realized that by using SUMPRODUCT this just takes all of the scores of those that failed the test and adds them together.  And I can't find anyway to get anything else to work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use MAX instead of SUMPRODUCT and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to Enter as an array formula.

Comment: `MAX(SUBTOTAL(104,OFFSET(INDEX(TOTAL,1),ROW(TOTAL)-ROW(INDEX(TOTAL,1)),0,1))*(PASS_FAIL="FAIL"))`

Comment: This gives me the overall max of TOTAL, not the conditional MAX given that the individual failed

Comment: It is working for me.

Comment: make sure you array enter the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Comment: I didn't change it to a * thank you so much!!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer below as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap in MAX instead of SUMPRODUCT and multiply the two conditionals:

```
=MAX(SUBTOTAL(104,OFFSET(C2,ROW(C2:C16)-MIN(ROW(C2:C16)),0,1,1))*(B2:B16="A"))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not edit a question to ask a new question.  Instead ask a new question in a new post.